# All buttons are pressed "on" on page load

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I got a very simple filter on website, which filters by toggling ON or OFF in various criteria for search(just like check boxes do). On page load I want all buttons be in "ON" as an initial (or checked, or pressed, whatever is ok for you) state. My [website](http://concept.com.kz/folio.html).
And this is my script in head of the page:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#Container').mixItUp({
        load: {
          filter: '.category-1'
        },
        controls: {
          toggleFilterButtons: true
        },          
        animation: {
        duration: 250,
        effects: 'fade translateZ(-360px) stagger(104ms) scale(0.83)',
        easing: 'ease'
        }

      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to make on page load all buttons be in "ON" (or checked, or pressed, whatever is ok for you) state?

Comment: I presume you mean how to select an HTML checkbox - `<input type="checkbox" name="myName" value="myValue" checked> Stuff the user sees`

Comment: No. you misunderstood. @Romski, please read my question one more time and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Buttons don't have a state of pressed or not pressed. You need a checkbox for that. Buttons just toggle. You need to change the default state for whatever the buttons are toggling.

Comment: How to change the "default state" of a button?

Comment: Again, buttons don't have state.

Comment: The buttons are toggling some other state. That state needs to have its default changed.

Comment: https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/advanced-filtering/ says that you can set `load.filter` to `'all'`. You probably need to actually call the function you're defining in the script tag in the head of the page.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Thanks, I finally made it with your help. Post the same as an "answer" and I will tick it as a "correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons don't have a state of pressed or not pressed. You need a checkbox for that. Buttons just toggle. You need to change the default state for whatever the buttons are toggling.

http://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/advanced-filtering says that you can set `load.filter` to `'all'`. You probably need to actually call the function you're defining in the script tag in the head of the page.